# Limit amout of sessions on user-by-user basis?

Tags: users, limit

I've searched and searched, but to no avail - hope you can help!

I'm building a subscription based online training site for a client. The service caters to companies, who will buy access for their employees. The service has different types of subscriptions, dependent on the amount of employees they wish to buy access - they can choose to buy access for either 10 to 15, 15 to 25 or 25+ of their employees.

Now, the thing is..
If a company buys access for 10-15 employees, for example, these employees will share the same login credentials. They will not get individual logins.

**WHICH IS WHY I am looking for a way to limit the amount of sessions on an individual user-by-user basis.**

I need to be able to differentiate between the tiers, the service offers. The plugins I can find, only have an option to limit the amount of sessions for ALL users on the entire site - not on individual users.

I hope I'm making sense. All help and input is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: As in you want to say User A can only be logged in "once", on a single browser? Will there ever be a use-case where User A wants to be logged in on both their desktop and mobile, or even two separate computers at the same time?

Comment: Yes, there will be simultaneous users on one account. I just need to restrict the amount of users that can use each account.

Example: Company A buy access for 15 employees. Company A receives a username and a password, that all of the 15 employees use to access the site. The site then needs to be able to limit the amount of employees that can access the site to 15, so if 30 employees try to log in to access the site, only 15 are able to. Does that make sense?

Comment: Kind of, but I don't know how you would distinguish one employee from 15 if they're all using the same login credentials. You really would need to allow them to have 15 accounts, or provide a list of valid user email addresses that are allowed access. You could manage that list somewhere, and then filter the logged in user's ability to use the site based on that list. I can't think of any realistic and reasonable way to determine that only 15 people are using the same login at any given time.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I will look into that. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help! It is enormously appreciate - hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

One user account per person would definitely be easier, but I think you could kind of get this done by playing with the user sessions, which are stored as `user_meta` with the `session_tokens` key. Something along these lines maybe.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_max_num_sessions');
function check_max_num_sessions() {
    // Only check for logged in users
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        // Get user sessions from user_meta
        $user_sessions = user_sessions($current_user_id);

        // Count sessions
        $ongoing_sessions = count_ongoing_sessions(
            $user_sessions
        );

        // Get max num of allowed sessions
        $max_sessions = max_num_sessions(
            $current_user_id
        );

        // Check, if limit exceeded
        if ( $ongoing_sessions > $max_sessions ) {

            // Destroy latest session
            destroy_latest_user_session(
                $current_user_id,
                $user_sessions
            );

            // Or destroy the current session, which may or may not be the latest
            // $session_manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance(
            //  $current_user_id
            // );
            // $session_manager->destroy(
            //  wp_get_session_token()
            // );

            // Redirect user to an error page?
            // wp_redirect(
            //  max_num_sessions_error_page(),
            //  302
            // );
            // exit;
        }
    }

}

function user_sessions(int $user_id) {
    $meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'session_tokens', true );
    return is_array($meta) ? $meta : array();
}

function destroy_latest_user_session(int $user_id, array $sessions) {
    array_pop(
        $sessions
    );
    return update_user_meta( $user_id, 'session_tokens', $sessions );
}

function count_ongoing_sessions( array $sessions ) {
    // Time to compare sessions against
    $now = current_time('timestamp');
    // Session counter
    $ongoing_sessions = 0;
    /**
        * Loop current user's sessions
        *
        * @var array $session
        * expiration int timestamp
        * ip string
        * ua (user agent) string
        * login int timestamp
        */
    foreach ($sessions as $session) {
        // Skip expired sessions
        if ( $session['expiration'] < $now ) {
            continue;
        }
        // maybe some user agent checking here, if needed
        // code..
        // Increment counter
        $ongoing_sessions++;
    }
    return $ongoing_sessions;
}

function max_num_sessions( int $user_id ) {
    // Get from database?
    return 15;
}

function max_num_sessions_error_page() {
    return 'http://example.com';
}
```

I didn't see a direct way to destroy latest session with `WP_Session_Tokens`. That's why I'm getting and updating the meta directly.

There probably should be a redirect after kicking the latest session, because the user will seem to be logged in, after the session meta has been updated, until the user navigates to another page or refreshes the current page and WP checks again the user's login status.